# What is the purpose of “Title” in a Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: web

I am new to stackoverflow and was completing my profile. I don't see any information on what 'Title' means to my profile. What kind of info should I put up there?

There isn't any description present on that page, and a Google search gives very irrelevant results.

Comment: This is not used much on Stack Overflow. It's kind of a quaint thing from 50 years ago when people would indicate Mr., Mrs., Prof., Dr., Lord etc.

Comment: oh..that was really simple..thank you so much @jarmod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Title is not used much on Stack Overflow though it is still common in more formal scenarios.

It's an entry on  a form where a person can indicate an [honorific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_honorifics) that describes them or that they have earned and prefer to be known by. It's a quaint thing from decades ago when people would indicate Mr., Mrs., Prof., Dr., Lord, Your Majesty etc.